# How to remove spaces from a xrange list - Python

Tags: python, xrange

Lets say I have:

```
hello = list(xrange(100))
print hello
```

The result is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...
```

I need to remove all those spaces from the list so it can be like:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...
```

Comment: `hello` will print a list object. Why is it a string object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `join` takes string objects, you need to convert those items explicitly to strings.  For example:

```
hello = ','.join(list(xrange(100)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```

So:

```
hello = xrange(100)
print ''.join([str(n) for n in hello])
```

Note there is no need for the `list()`.

Comment: No need for the list comprehension. Pass the generator expression to `join`